# How do you get an element with a certain class within $(this) in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a function that process form data through ajax. I've got the function written, but in the end, once I've got the data, I need to put a message into a div within the submitted form. The div has a class of 'message'.

When referring to the form as `$(this)` in my function, how would I get to the div with the class of "message" within it?  (So the equivalent of `$('form.message')`, but using `$(this)` instead of form)

Comment: Probably a typo: `$('form.message')` would select every form with class `message`, not the element with this class inside the form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give your selector context:

```
$(".message", this);
```

That's all :)

Comment: No worries. Strive to make answers more clear and you'll get more upvotes.

Comment: must have missed the selector he was asking for.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$(this).children('.message')
```

Depending on the structure/lay out of your html this should work.

If not you should post your html so we can have a better idea of what your trying to do.

Comment: Or `.find()` (which would be the equivalent for `$('form .message')`.

Comment: @PENDO method is better in that case, as children will search in one sublevel of $(this), at least find() would be better. From jQuery doc: "The .find() and .children() methods are similar, except that the latter only travels a single level down the DOM tree"

Comment: @regilero: I completely agree with you because @Zak never said that DIV is immediate child of `this`. He just said it's *within it*.

Comment: Hence my comment: "Depending on the structure/lay out of your html this should work. If not you should post your html so we can have a better idea of what your trying to do." From a performance standpoint, children is the best choice.

Comment: or instead provide both possibilities (since there are just two of them) and explain when each of them should be used and why. That would surely get you more upvotes and no downvote (even though I didn't downvoted you)